# Retrofit how to use colon in url?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, google-photos

I am developing an Android app using Google Photo API.

I am trying to upload an image file into the Google Photo Server using below API.

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/batchCreate

According to the document, I should use below URL to upload an image file.

```
POST https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate
```

So I write the code using the retrofit.

```
@Headers("Content-type: application/json")
@POST("mediaItems:batchCreate") // The point is here
fun batchCreate(@Header("Authorization") authorization: String, @Body batchCreateRequest: BatchCreateRequest): Observable<BatchCreateResponse>
```

When I run it, IllegalArgumentException occurred.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL. Base: https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/, Relative: mediaItems:batchCreate

What can I do solve this problem?

Comment: can you show the code which creates retrofit with BASE_URL ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `@POST("./mediaItems:batchCreate")` instead of `@POST("mediaItems:batchCreate")`

Comment: Not working for resources like @POST("./orders/{orderId}/invitations:stop"), throws IllegalArgumentException @Path parameters shouldn't perform path traversal ('.' or '..'):